# NPN Switch when ON operating in Forward Active or Saturation Region?

Tags: switches, npn, saturation

When an NPN transistor is used as a switch as shown below, is it operating in the Forward Active Region or the Saturation region when it is turned ON? I believe its working in the Forward Active Region since V_BC = 0V < 0.4V and V_BE = 0.7V. I read somewhere that an NPN is in saturation when operated as a switch in the shown configuration. I'd appreciate if someone can clarify.

[image]

Comment: \$V_{CE}\$ when the transistor is on will indicate if it is in saturation.  In your case \$V_{CE} = 0.7~V\$ and therfore not in saturation.

Comment: @skvery how do you know V_CE=0.7 V?

Comment: \$V_{BC} = 0~V\$

Comment: Saturation is a property of a circuit, not a property of a transistor in isolation. When \$\vert V_{CE}\vert \lt \vert V_{BE}\vert\$ then the transistor is moving into saturation.

Comment: Use a multimeter to measure the voltage from emitter to collector when your CONTROL input is at 5V. If the measured voltage is less than say about 0.5V then the transistor is for sure saturated.

Comment: Yes Obviously saturated as he implied \$Vce=Vbe-Vbc ~~\$=0.7-0.4=0.3  If Vce< Vbe it is in saturation, ie if **Vbc>0** but under high currents saturation often begins to cause THD from a reduction in hFE Vce<1V all the time and Vce<2V in some of the devices.  Vce is always given in specs as Vce(sat) but is by definition the value of saturation, but it starts at a higher voltage from distortion.

Comment: Saturation specs are almost always given now for Ic/Ib=10 (some 20:1) but often work with 10% of typical hFE but it can still be partially in saturation in high hFE devices with Ic/Ib=50 or about 50% of the typical hFE so marginal linear/saturation and depends on application.

Comment: Practically speaking, your transistor would be in saturation. You can seee this easily by just looking at the 10:1 ratio of base resistor to collector resistor. If the base current is 4.3mA, and the beta is 50, the collector current would have to be over 200mA to be in the linear region. But with only 5V across 100 Ohms, you will never get 200 mA. (0.2A * 100 Ohms = 20V).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fast calculation: ON-state Ib is about 4.3mA. (= (5V-0.7V)/1kOhm). If the transistor has current gain =50, then the Ic should be 50 * 4.3mA = 215mA.

R2 and +5VDC supply limits the Ic under 5V/100Ohm = 50mA. So there's at least 4x exessive Ib, the transistor is heavily saturated.

Due led's voltage drop (often about 1.5V) the theoretical max current is probably only 35mA. This gives more reason to believe the saturation to be true.

The current gain =50 is only a quess, but be it even as low as 25, the transistor is still heavily saturated.

**This was not asked, but maybe it's interesting:** The saturation is resulted from exessive Ib. This is done to be sure that different individual transistors of same type surely have enough Ib for proper(= low voltage drop) switching. The saturation makes the return to off-state slow and delayed, but often this is not harmful. High power high frequency pulse circuits suffer much if the action is slow or delayed. It causes exessive heating. Even short circuits are possible if there is a temporary current path through transistors right from +supply to GND or -supply.